# How do I call two functions asynchronously, in parallel, in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've got two static functions that are independent of each other and consume a large amount of resources when they're used individually.

```
public static class Helper(){
    public static void A(string username, int power, Model model)
        { /* do A things to the model */ }
    public static void B(string username, Model model)
        { /* do B things to the model */ }
}
```

Right now, they're called as

```
public ActionResult Home(){
    Model model = new Model();
    A("Jared", 9001, model);
    B("Jared", model);
    return View("Home", model);
}
```

In my controller (attn: not real code).

I want them to work side by side, asynchronously, and then when they're both done I'd like to return to synchronous processing in order to return the View with the updated model.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've never worked with asynchronous C# or threaded C# before, so it's been hard for me to decipher the examples I've uncovered.

TIA

Comment: it seems like you could do what `B` does inside of `A`.

Comment: Could you please use a title that describes your problem instead of the vaguest title ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick..

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Home()
{ 
  var model = new Model();
  var t1 = Helper.A("Jared", 9001, model);
  var t2 = Helper.B("Jared", model);

  await Task.WhenAll(new [] { t1, t2 });

  return View("Home", model);
}

public static class Helper
{
  public static async Task A(string username, int power, Model model)
  {
    /* do A things to the model */ 
  }
  public static async Task B(string username, Model model)
  {
    /* do B things to the model */ 
  }
}
```

There's a big "gotcha" with this though. The model must be able to handle  `A()` and `B()` working in parallel.

Comment: @jadaho The "anonymous array" isn't anonymous. It's type is  `Task[]`, but it's just implicitly typed. Similar to using `var myInt = 0;` rather than `int myInt = 0;`.

Comment: Can you please show an example for the "Gotcha" part?

Comment: @student A good example would be if both `A()` and `B()` were both reading and writing to the same property on the `Model`. Especially if both operations have business logic based on the value of the specific property.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean, asynchronously in parallel.

First update your functions to match something like this:

```
public static async Task A(Model model) { /* ... */ }
public static async Task B(Model model) { /* ... */ }
```

Then update your calling code to look something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Home() { 
    var taskA = A(model);
    var taskB = B(model);

    await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);
    return View("Home", model);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use Task Parallel Library like described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.